# Trigger Jquery function onclick

Tags: jquery

I have a Jquery function that I would like to trigger on or off from a mouse click.
The area to trigger the on state is an anchor tag with the class of 'inline_sprite' and the area to trigger the off state is an anchor tag with the class of 'block_sprite'.
The Jquery function wraps several divs within a table.

I'm new to Jquery and unsure of the correct syntax, any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the jquery code:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#page-wrap").wrapInner("<table cellspacing='30'><tr>");
    $(".post").wrap("<td>");
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you're new to jQuery you'd benefit from checking out http://try.jquery.com.

Comment: There's a reason there is no `unWrapInner()` function available, it gets kinda complicated, depending on the markup etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a click function for element with class `inline_sprite` -- This adds to the class

```
$(".inline_sprite").click(function() {
     $("#page-wrap").wrapInner("<table cellspacing='30'><tr>");
     $(".post").wrap("<td>");
});
```

You'll need to create separate logic to remove it, heres the click handler though

```
$(".block_sprite").click(function() { //code });
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. Probably missing something very obvious? Here's my amended code: `$(".inline_sprite").click(function() {
  $("#contentPrint,#contentHome").wrapInner("<table><tr>");
  $(".hScroll").wrap("<td></td>");` `<a class="inline_sprite "href="#" target="_self"></a>
<a class="block_sprite "href="#" target="_self"></a>`

Comment: This fixed my problem, but I needed to add a document ready function to begin with so the DOM was fully loaded. Worked like a treat after that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".inline_sprite").on("click", function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this to track the click on off and on

```
$('.inline_sprite').bind('click',function(){
        alert('On');
});

$('.block_sprite').bind('click',function(){
    alert('off');
});
```

Here is a live working example http://jsfiddle.net/87xqJ/3/